# Removing all ACLs from Directories and Subdirectories in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, access-control-list

how do I remove all ACLS in a folder and subfolder and all their content.

Really I just want to stop using ACLs.

Currently im using   `setfacl -b NAME`

But this is per ACL basis. Is there a way to turn it off system wide in FREEBSD

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply stop using ACLs on an entire disk, I'd suggest mounting the disks with the 'noacl' option (in /etc/fstab).  It's a simple and fast way to do what you are asking.

Comment: My fstab looks like this /dev/ufs/FreeNASs1a / ufs ro 1 1
/dev/ufs/FreeNASs3 /cfg ufs rw,noauto 2 2
/dev/ufs/FreeNASs4 /data ufs rw,noatime 2 2
/dev/ada0p1.eli none                    swap            sw              0       0

Where would I put the noacl command ?

Comment: rw,noacl,noauto